# shell script to change IPs and save the new files

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a text file containing different IP addresses. I need to write a script to find the lines with IP (there are other lines) and increase the last digit by 1. This should be done  50 times!

It means there will be 50 new files to be saved. I don't want to use the logic to go to line number and replace the specific character.

Also the file name is present inside the file which should be increased 1 again. I am using `sed` but cannot achieve the correct loop and options.

the input file is example1:

```
 'name example101' 
'ip-address  10.255.255.13'
state enabled 
 'ip-address 10.255.253.45' 
'ip-address 10.255.255.13' 
'ip-address 10.0.0.130'
```

the first new file is example102 (the last one will be example150):

```
 'name example102' 
'ip-address  10.255.255.14'
state enabled 
 'ip-address 10.255.253.46' 
'ip-address 10.255.255.14' 
'ip-address 10.0.0.131'
```

Answer (score 2):

To increase IP you can use this regex:

```
perl -lpe 's/((\d{1,3}\.){3})(\d{1,3})/$1 . ($3 + 1)/eg' FILE
```

To increase 'name example101' you can try an expression like it.

Comment: perl -lpe 's/((\d{1,3}\.){3})(\d{1,3})/$1 . ($3 + 1)/eg' is working fine but I noticed that I should ignore a specific ip in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring a specific ip using `?!`

```
perl -lpe 's/((ip-address\s+(?!10\.255\.253\.45)((\d{1,3}\.){3}))(\d{1,3}))/$2.($5 + 1)/eg;s/(example)(\d{3})/$1.($2 + 1)/eg;' FILE
```

add ip to ignore in `(?!10\.255\.253\.45)` part

**UPDATE:** Added part `s/(example)(\d{3})/$1.($2 + 1)/eg;` to increment input string example101 to make it example102.

Comment: It is not working. It seems not a generic solution; it changes some Ips not the rest. also still thinking on how to add an option to make example101 example102 in multiple lines inside the file.

Comment: @Ephieste- It was not running for you because,you must be having different number of spaces after `ip-address` in your input file.Check now.

Comment: @Ephieste- Added option for example101.Please check.

Comment: perl -lpe 's/((\d{1,3}\.){3})(\d{1,3})/$1 . ($3 + 1)/eg unless /\b\Q10.255.244.12\E\b/;s/(example)(\d{3})/$1.($2 + 1)/eg;' example101  >> example102
This combination solved my problem but I have to add "unless" statement to ignore one ip. and also will try to

Comment: @Ephieste - ok.That's good too.You can post that as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I could do this in a few seconds interactively in Vim. In Vim, `Ctrl-A` increments the number under the cursor. Search for IP address, go to last octet, increment. Record in a keyboard macro under register `a`, invoke as `@a`, then repeat N more times by holding down `@@`.

Here are the exact keystrokes:

Start recording:

```
qa
```

Search for start of next IPv4 address:

```
 /\([0-9]\+\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\+[Enter]
```

Jump to dot before last octet (3 times forward to dot):

```
 3f.
```

Increment:

```
 Ctrl-A
```

Finish recording:

```
 q
```

Now, run the macro again:

```
 @a
```

Repeat (hold down your @ key to auto-repeat):

```
 @@
```

If notice you've edited an IP that you shouldn't have just use `u` to undo as many times as necessary, skip it, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

This command-line program increments all the numbers (including the file number) except IP address `10.0.0.130`. If there are more than one or two addresses to be ignored this method will become unwieldy and you should do something like putting all the immutable addresses in a file or the `__DATA__` section of the program.

```perl
perl -pe "s/(\d+)('\s*)$/($1+1).$2/e unless /\b\Q10.0.0.130\E\b/" ipfile
```

**output**

```
 'name example102'
'ip-address  10.255.255.14'
state enabled
 'ip-address 10.255.253.46'
'ip-address 10.255.255.14'
'ip-address 10.0.0.130'
```

---

**Edit**

To add a second exclusion to the modifications, this command also protects `0.0.0.0`

```perl
perl -pe "s/(\d+)('\s*)$/($1+1).$2/e unless /\b\Q10.0.0.130\E|\Q0.0.0.0\E\b/" ipfile
```

Comment: This fails if the above input is in one line.

Comment: thank you, unless is working just I need one more exception for ip 0.0.0.0

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to add a second address to be excluded from modification.